# Parallel transport as projection from an ambient metric

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

Consider the situation where you have a manifold embedded in an ambient Euclidean space (for example, the surface of a sphere $S^2$ living in $R^3$). I am commonly told that I can parallel transport a vector by two steps. Step 1: Transport the vector in the flat/Euclidean space to a new point. Step 2: Project the result onto the tangent space at the new point. However, I don't see how this preserves the norm.

In the example, consider a vector pointing North at the equator. Say that the vector has coordinates (0,0,z) in the ambient $R^3$ and is based at (1,0,0)). Move it to the North pole at (0,0,1). Now project. The result is 0, when it should be something like (-z,0,0) if we transport on the shortest geodesic.

I don't think this is related to the fact we can't put global coordinates/uniquely define parallel transport on $S^2$. This example also works for $S^1$ embedded in $R^2$, where parallel transport is uniquely defined, since the space $S^1$ is intrinsically flat.

One possible resolution I see is to say that this projection picture only holds locally. Something like: the norm changes at second order only, so we can neglect this.

Comment: You transport it *infinitesimally*, project, then transport it again infinitesimally, then project, and so on, until you get to the desired point. Doesn't work with finite translations, unless you do it sequentially with infinitesimal ones.

Comment: ^^ this should be an answer to this question.  Note that this process is path-dependent.